# How can you troubleshoot GMailApp.search in Google App Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api

I'm deploying my Google App Scripts app as a webapp, run as my account (to be able to access my messages with GMailApp).
In there, I have a function that sends an email to a customer (using MailApp), like this:

```
  let messageID = MailApp.sendEmail({
    from: 'myaccount@mydomain.com',
    to: 'customerEmail@example.com',
    subject: 'My title',
    htmlBody: replyTemplate.evaluate().getContent(),
  });
```

Then there's another function, using GMailApp, searching for threads with a customer, like this:

```
  let gmailQuery = 'from:customerEmail@example.com OR to:customerEmail@example.com';
  let searchResults = GmailApp.search(gmailQuery, 1, 20);
```

This second function not always returns a result, even if when I execute the same query in GMail directly I *do* have results. Most of times, my app sends the email and right after it goes finding it back: the message is there, but I get no results.
In DevTools console, network tabs I see no errors.
How can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: There is ``console`` on the server side.

Comment: You can also check the execution log to see if there are any errors server side.

Comment: Nope, no errors in execution logs, I just get zero results.

Comment: If you wish to get the first thread returned then you should use zero for the first index or limit yourself to one parameter in the call to search

Comment: First step in trouble shooting might be to learn how to debug javascript in chrome developer tools and they spend some time with the script editors debugger.

Comment: @Cooper: your zero index suggestion was right to the point! Thanks a lot.
As for debugging with (DevTools or) the script editor's, I usually do that but never did it with a deployed webapp, I'll give it a try, thanks!